# Slim HttpBasicAuth

Tags: php, slim, basic-authentication

I have single page REST application and I'm trying to add there some really simple authorisation. Just login, no registration.
I am using HTTP Basic Authentication middleware with simple PDO authenticator, by Mika Tuupola. This is part of my code:

```
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
    require '../src/config.php';

    $app = new Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);


    $container = $app->getContainer();
    $container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $db = $c['settings']['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $db['host'] . ";dbname=" . $db['dbname'],
        $db['user'], $db['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};


$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "path" => "/roomPictures",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "authenticator" => new PdoAuthenticator([
        "pdo" => $pdo
    ])
]));


require '../src/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

After reloading mypage.dev/roomPictures I just get 500 Internal server error.
Do you guys have any idea what I might have been doing wrong?

I'm not sure if I understand this right, but after triggering /roomPictures, the system dialog window asking about username and password should appear?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at your error logs.

Comment: duplicate question, see your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168362/slim-basic-authentication).

Comment: it is not quite the same, in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Either add the following line to your code:

```
use Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication\PdoAuthenticator;
```

Or alternatively instantiate the middleware as:

```
$app->add(new Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "path" => "/roomPictures",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "authenticator" => new Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication\PdoAuthenticator([
        "pdo" => $pdo
    ])
]));
```

Comment: I tried the second option. In the line "pdo" => $pdo the editor is saying that $pdo is an undefined variable. How could I solve this?

Comment: Define the $pdo variable or alternatively pass the $container['db'] where you are defining the $pdo variable.

Comment: like this? $app = new Slim\App(['settings' => $config]); $pdo_var = $container['db']; And then "pdo" => $pdo_var ???